# OpenSSL EVP API and CLI mismatch for AES256

Tags: c, encryption, openssl

I'm trying to make a C program and openssl CLI generate consistent output for AES encryption.

For encryption, I'm using this C and OpenSSL EVP example: https://wiki.openssl.org/index.php/EVP_Symmetric_Encryption_and_Decryption#Encrypting_the_message

And it is invoked as follows:

```
....
#include <openssl/conf.h>
#include <openssl/evp.h>
#include <openssl/err.h>
....

int main()
{
    char ciphertext[1024];
    static char *enckey = (char *) "7c07f68ea8494b2f8b9fea297119350d78708afa69c1c7600000000000000000";
    static char *iv = (char *)"FEDCBA09876543210000000000000000";
    size_t* output_length;
    
    ssize_t crypto_length = encrypt("test", 4, enckey, iv, ciphertext);
    
    printf("%s", base64_encode(ciphertext, crypto_length, output_length) );
}
```

For OpenSSL CLI I'm using:

```
openssl enc -aes-256-cbc -e -a -A -in input.dat \
  -K 7c07f68ea8494b2f8b9fea297119350d78708afa69c1c7600000000000000000 -iv FEDCBA09876543210000000000000000
```

Identical key, IV, plaintext (the input.dat has just "test" inside (without quotes)), identical mode - AES-256-CBC.

And yet, I get two different outputs:

- EVP+C: `HBy5KT15kp+dLFuBNU15rw==`
- CLI: `zcTjiVTkZI8XSpDbc0HvRA==` (I get the same with a Java program with the same parameters)

Any idea why these would generate different outputs, and therefore the EVP output can't be decrypted in CLI.

Comment: I don't see any EVP code, it must be in the `encrypt()` method.

Comment: However, you will have to explicitly hex-decode that key and IV in your C code. The CLI does that for you.

Comment: Thanks, that fixes it.

Comment: static char *iv = (char *)"\xFE\xDC\xBA\x09\x87\x65\x43\x21\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00";